# Counting matches between two tables

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have a table of words and a table of phrases.  I'd like to count how many phrases contain each word.

This query gives me a list of (word, phrase) pairs; how do I get the count?  Is there a more efficient way to do it?

select words.word, phrases.phrase

from words left join phrases

on phrases.phrase rlike concat('(^|[^a-z])', words.word, '($|[^a-z])');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing query, you can add a `GROUP BY` clause and a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    words.word,
    COUNT(phrases.phrase) as Count
FROM
    words
    LEFT JOIN phrases
        ON phrases.phrase RLIKE CONCAT('(^|[^a-z])', words.word, '($|[^a-z])')
GROUP BY
    words.word
```

Alternatively, you can achieve this with a sub-query instead of a join:

```
SELECT
    words.word,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM phrases
        WHERE phrase RLIKE CONCAT('(^|[^a-z])', words.word, '($|[^a-z])')
    ) AS Count
FROM words
```